# Generating HTML tables in PHP and passing into Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Essentially, I am trying to build a booking system. The booking table shows the bookings for an entire week, and the user can switch between weeks.

In PHP, I have a function get_booking_table which returns the html for the booking table, based on an input (which week) and booking availabilities (from mysql):

```
<?php
  function get_booking_table($week_number) {
    //retrieve various data from mysql database, return html string
  }
```

I am then loading this html for each week into a JS array, so that the table for each week can be loaded quickly when the user changes week.

My problem is that the HTML string being returned from the PHP function is very long, which I have read is bad practice (as well as being clunky for me to handle). The only way I can think of to avoid this is to instead create a 2D array for the booking table for each week, somehow pass this into JS code, and then generate the HTML code from the JS 2D array. However, this seems even more overly complicated.

What is the correct way to create a dynamic HTML table in PHP and load it into JS?

Comment: How many weeks total are loaded in at a time?

Comment: what is "very long"? it's not that long html is bad, it's that stuffing raw html in a variable into the DOM can be slow, as the new html has to be parsed. for "short" html, it's no big deal, but if you're inserting 10 meg of table tags, then yeah - it's going to be a bit of a dog.

Comment: Why don't you serialize data from php into a json and get the data with async request from javascript and render the data accordingly. Using view library like React is perfect for the job.

Comment: About 4 weeks are loaded. I might have overexaggerated with the 'very long', it's certainly not long enough to cause performance issues. However, in the function I have to do a lot of concatentions and sprintf, and its enough to make the function very messy.

Comment: I like using DataTables for the front-end, they have functionality to work with AJAX; you just setup the PHP page to echo entries in JSON format, and use the DataTables built-in AJAX methods to retrieve and parse the JSON data.

Comment: Would prefer not to use async requests, since my system is pretty simple and doesn't deal with a lot of data - it can all be loaded quite efficiently I think. I am quite new to PHP and JS (and haven't explored JSON) though so will have a look at that if it is the best way, thanks.

Comment: `"Would prefer not to use async requests, since my system is pretty simple and doesn't deal with a lot of data"`...that statement doesn't make any sense to me. You want to load something via Javascript but it comes from a PHP page, so you use Ajax...has nothing to do with how big the system is.

Comment: If it isn't affecting performance, maybe you should just look into ways to make your function less messy?

Comment: Sorry, I worded that badly. I actually meant that (as Source Matters' answer states) that I could just load the data into a JS array immediately after the page loads. The HTML content does change, and I could use AJAX for that, but there only a few possibilities for the content (different week) and I can just store the HTML for all possible weeks in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much what the others have stated. This used to be my "go-to" method for a long time: have PHP echo out some nice HTML and "spit it out" on the javascript side. Works for some situations, but usually "feels" lazy (to me personally).

The best method is as described: Use an ajax request to your PHP page that outputs a json_encoded PHP array (it's literally just wrapping your normal PHP array in the json_encoded function). Then, in your ajax's "success" method, go to town parsing the json object. You can use a library like DataTables (that was mentioned) to do this REALLY fast, and it gives you a lot of added functionality (sorting, re-ordering columns, etc.)

Also worth noting, it doesn't sound like you're doing anything with the HTML once it's generated. So if you wanted to, you could do exactly as you're already doing and output the HTML from your PHP script. Not pretty (or fun to maintain), but it works...

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up (along with all the comments). I have an idea now how to implement the AJAX with json_encoding (having just read about it) but having thought about it more, in my case there is very little change in HTML content after generation, so for simplicity I might take the 'lazy' route and just store all necessary content in JS upon page load.